# How to find a formula for horizontal composition?

Tags: category-theory

For natural transformations $F_1 \xrightarrow{\alpha} F_2$ and $G_1 \xrightarrow{\beta} G_2$, I have proven that $(\beta \star \alpha)_X := G_2(\alpha_X) \circ \beta_{F_1X}$ is a natural transformation from $G_1 \circ F_1$ to $G_2 \circ F_2$.

Imagine you are Saunders / MacLane creating Category Theory. You want to work out as much as possible in short time and to find a natural transformation for composed functors. But how do you find this concrete formula for the horizontal composition *in a clever way*?

Since I am new in Category Theory, my (elaborated) proof of naturality consists of one and a half page and needed some hours. The formula consist of multiple characters. Hence brute-force (generate all combinations, check if the domains / codomains agree, if yes, try to prove naturality) seems not to be the most time efficient way to work.

Searching math.SE, I found questions for applications of horizontal composition and for the idea of horizontal composition itself as well as a [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700543/having-trouble-proving-natural-transformation-horizontal-composition-equality-of) of natural equivalence to another formula, but not how to develop the concrete definition of $(\beta \star \alpha)_X$.

Comment: As you say, there are many constraints. I would even say that the constraints force the answer. So perhaps you should try thinking a bit harder about how to satisfy the constraints, rather than just brute forcing it.

Comment: The constraints consist in the syntax correctness (which many formulae fulfill) as well as in the validity of an equation which does contain on both sides the unknown term in a stable way, such that the usual "circling-around-calculations" with the intent to get low-hanging -- but general -- fruits are not possible. At least, I can't think of a way to do them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is better understood as "homotopies".

A little analogy before going into details. Suppose you have $f_1, f_2 : X \to Y$ honotopic one to another through $\alpha : X \times I \to Y$ and $g_1, g_2 : Y \to Z $ homotopic one to another through $\beta: Y \times I \to Z$.

How would you produce an homotopy between $g_1f_1$ and $g_2 f_2$ ? Well we surely have a map

$$ \gamma: X\times I^2 \to Y \times I \to Z$$

Where the first map applies $\alpha$ to the first two components and second map is just $\beta$. Notice also that $\gamma(x,0,0) = g_1 f_1, \gamma(x,1,1) = g_2 f_2 $. In order for $\gamma$ to be an homotopy it should really start from $X \times I$. Since we want our homotopy to start at $g_1 f_1 $ and finish at $g_2 f_2$, it is sensible to precompose with the diagonal $I \to I^2$.

So now we define

$$( \beta \star \alpha ) (x, t) = \beta( \alpha(x, t), t) $$

And we are done. But how the hell this is relevant to categories?? In the modern viewpoint, categories are thought as 1 dimensional spaces in a sense. Here is the plot twist: we have an "interval object" in categories given by $I = \{ 0 \to 1\}$. It is the category with two objects and one arrow from 0 to 1 (which I denote by $01$). I let you show that it plays the same role as in spaces (with the exception that here homotopies have a direction) : a natural transformation $\alpha : F_1 \to F_2$ between two functors $F_1, F_2 : C \to D $ is the same as a functor $C \times I \to D$.

What does it happen if you repeat the argument of spaces for functors..? Well, we will end up with a formula and guess what..! It is the right one. I think it is very instructive for you to fill in the details. Feel free to comment if you have any doubts!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this enlightening and ingenious explanation! I will try to do the proofs.

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to draw diagrams and see how to make sense of them.
[image: possible way to break question down]

In this picture you have to think first of what $\beta \circ F_1$ might mean, and what $G_2 \circ \alpha$ might mean as natural transformations. Draw more diagrams and there is really only one way to go at that point.
Of course there is another diagram you can draw to start with. This gives another answer and you can then think if the two answers are equal. Having a plausible picture as a prompt is usually going to be much more productive than generating combinations of symbols in a brute force fashion.

Comment: It's annoying that I am not able to give the "solution" property to multiple answers. Thanks a lot for your answer! It shows a sensible and efficient work approach which seems to lie on the street. A little embarassing that I was not able to find this ansatz myself.